# Pandas multiple condition and get dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a datafram df, and i want to get the rows that
a column value equals 1 b 0 c 0 and d 0

```
df_result = df[df.a == 1 and df.b == 0 and df.c == 0 and df.d == 0]
```

It says ;
The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: try to use `.eq` instead of `==`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `&` instead of `and` and put brackets around each value test:

```
df_result = df[(df.a == 1) & (df.b == 0) & (df.c == 0) & (df.d == 0)]
```

Alternatively, to avoid using extra brackets, you can use `.eq()`:

```
df_result = df[df.a.eq(1) & df.b.eq(0) & df.c.eq(0) & df.d.eq(0)]
```

Comment: or query, check dupe.

Comment: Thank you, i want to drop this rows from data set what should i do?